# Remix.run nested routes causing multiple renders

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Re: remix version - 1.7.2

I setup two levels of nested routes in a vanilla remix app. For the second level routes, clicking on the Link renders the child component multiple times. My understanding was that remix would only render the necessary child component once.

Here's the nested file structure:

```
.
├── entry.client.tsx
├── entry.server.tsx
├── root.tsx
└── routes
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── pages
    │   ├── $pagesId.tsx
    │   └── index.tsx
    └── pages.tsx
```

The child component in `$pagesId.tsx` gets called multiple times every time a link route in the parent `pages.tsx` is clicked.

Here's a short screen recording of the behavior - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc1yI.jpg

Here's the stackblitz running an example of the app - https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-1zuqsu?file=app%2Froutes%2Fpages%2F%24pagesId.tsx

Thank you.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, this might be expected with the way transitions are done, but it basically means every navigation reloads things three times. Were you able to figure anything more out on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `useTransition` hook, you'll see why Remix is re-rendering your routes. React re-renders you app as needed. Remix is updating its root context, which filters through routes. Remember, re-render doesn't mean re-paint. So unless your renders are very slow, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

To make it clear, I'm clicking between the two idle states.

`idle -> loading -> idle | click | idle -> loading -> idle`

[image: dev console log of transition state]